# Date and time column in Custom List form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, date-time

I have created a Date and time type column in my custom list and have selected "Date Only" for Display format, but it is always displaying the options to select data as well as time on the form. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Where exactly have you selected "Date only"?

Comment: SP designer -> List -> Edit list columns -> double click the date and time column -> display format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have selected date only then create a new form using sharepoint designer. In the new form you will be able to see field in date only format.